# Constant time algorithm to find closest multiple of an integer a less than integer b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, euclidean-algorithm

Thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose I have two integers, $a$ and $b$.  I want to find the multiple of $a$ that is less than $b$ but closest to $b$.  For example, suppose $a = 3$ and $b = 15$.  The answer here would be 12.

Asked another way, I want to find the largest multiple of $a$ that is less than $b$.

Is there a constant time algorithm to do this?  If not, is using modular arithmetic the most efficient solution?

edit:
I know how to solve this problem.  I'm asking if there is a way to solve this problem in constant time (ie computational complexity).  Modular, multiplication (ie division), and addition are not constant time operations.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations from more info regarding computational complexity.

I should have been more clear too.  I don't believe that there is a constant time algorithm, but I could be wrong.  Even if there isn't what would be the most computationally efficient way of solving this?

Comment: Define "*most efficient solution*", especially since you don't consider addition to be constant time. In practice, one would use integer division and multiplication $a \cdot \lfloor \frac{b-1}{a} \rfloor$ which are cheap in most cases.

Comment: By most efficient solution, I mean in terms of computational complexity.  ie the number of steps needed by a Turing machine.  On a real world computer, addition is constant time assuming that the sum of the two numbers being added fits within a machine word (ie 64 bits on most modern computers).  In the context of this problem though, it likely doesn't make a difference if you consider addition constant or linear.  The optimal algorithm is still likely the same.

Comment: It very well could be that integer division and multiplication is the optimal way about solving this problem (it is definitely the most obvious and natural).  It also possible though that there is a particular distribution whereby an answer can be found in constant time via a lookup within the distribution (think hashmap).  It's this thought that led me to ask the question.